# Android - is this a memory leak?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I have constructed a mechanism for observing when an object gets garbage collected passing a weak reference of it. Every few seconds it logs all the objects that have been passed to it and are not null.

I made this to observe when the context of a certain activity becomes null to make sure that I don't have a memory leak there.

So with this tool I noticed that when I hit back and the activity finished, the context of the activity does not get nullified. If I cause GC from device monitor or if I navigate through other activities it eventually gets gargage collected.

I thought it should be nullified immediately. Does this constitute a memory leak  or is it something I should be worried about?

Comment: No thats probably because it is moved to the memory cache, so whenever this memory space is required the GC collect it and remove it to make more space.

Comment: [Leakcanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary) is really good and easy to use library for finding those kinds of problems.

Comment: this looks interesting...I ll try it.

Comment: +1 for LeakCanary. I've been using for long time, it's a very nice library that in its heart, does the same you suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the memory monitor, and look at the `free` and `allocated` graphs while navigating through the app. You will see that the `allocated` graph decreases at times, most often when it nears or will overshoot the top of the `free` graph. That is when garbage collection happens.

> I thought it should be nullified immediately. Does this constitute a memory leak or is it something I should be worried about?

So no, it should not be nullified immediately, but only when a GC is initiated.